# emacs as python IDE vs pycharm: spacemacs and code navigation

Tags: python, spacemacs, anaconda-mode

**[2016.12.23]:**
I'm trying to make emacs be usable for working with python code.
By 'usable' I mean I could rely on it with code navigation and completion.

I'm using spacemacs + anaconda-mode for it, but I'm not 100% satisfied.

For example, when I try to visit definition of 'get' function with M-. (anaconda-mode-find-definitions), I end up with message: "no definitions found". On the other hand, PyCharm does the job with it.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

from avocado import Test

class MyTest(Test):   # M-. on 'Test' ends up in test class. This is fine.

    def test_mine(self):
        myParam = self.params.get(key='myParm', path='/', default=None)  ## M-. on 'get' fails. PyCharm does the job.

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

I also tried to use elpy+jedi, but no luck as well.

What is Your experience with this simple example?

The code above uses avocado testing framework.

regards

**[2016.12.27]:**
Below is another example, yet one I need, but hopefully also using more maintainable library, scapy: the packet forging library. All three imports are legal to execute the code, but only the last one makes emacs be able to jump to definition

```
#from scapy.all import *     # imports all from scapy.layers.all, but it is not enough for emacs to see IP() def.
#from scapy.layers.all import * # gets all from scapy.layers.inet, but it is not enough for emacs to see IP() def.
from scapy.layers.inet import *   #. ok with this.

packet = IP()
print packet.mysummary()
```

Question is is it possible to make emacs jump to definition when either first or second header is used instead of third one?

**[2016.12.28]:**
Here is another example where my emacs python environment neither completes nor jumps to definition, although the code runs without error. it requires "pip install pyvim pyvmomi".

```
from pyVmomi import vim

vim.vm.CloneSpec()
```

How about Your emacs environments, do they handle such cases?

Comment: Welcome to Emacs.SE!  Please edit your post to ask a more discrete question.  Explain precisely what the problem is.  Show the relevant code from your init file.

Comment: I attempted to reproduce it but even after installing avocado package I am stuck with an import error when I do `from avocado import Test`.

Comment: I had a little bit of experience with Intellij products for dynamic languages, but not Python (mostly Ruby). The thing is: often times it just guesses. As per your example, I wouldn't expect an honest code analyzer to suggest you any source for `get` method, or multiple possible sources. Finally, in Python it is possible to write code that generates methods dynamically, when they are called, so there isn't a universal way to find the source for a method - it simply may not even exist in your code base.

Comment: Please use some other example -- `avocado-framework` is a pain to install, making it hard to reproduce your example.

Comment: Thank You people for Your comments. I'll find another examples then. I'm starting with spacemacs+anaconda. I'm working with avocado at work (redhat install), and indeed trying to install it on ubuntu isn't that easy.

Comment: Here is another example, yet one I need, but also hopefully using more maintainable library, scapy: the packet forging library.

Comment: Maybe you want to ask the authors of these plugins about their opinions.  If I'm not mistaken anaconda uses jedi internally.

Comment: I use `jedi-core` + `importmagic` + `nose` + `py-isort` + `py-yapf` + `sphinx-doc` + `virtualenvwrapper` and happy with them.